# Web Sphere + IMessageConsumer + receiving messages

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'd like to receive messages from a web sphere queue. So I create a session, than I create a IMessageConsumer and I call one of the methods: Receive or ReceiveNoWait. The problem is that I can't receive any messages. Receive simply waits and ReceiveNoWait returns null. I want to read messages that have already been added to the queue. Any help ?

Comment: Hard to respond to this without knowing how you are connecting, whether you can see the active connections on the QMgr, etc.  Can you expand the question with additional details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you started the connection? That's a classic reason for not getting messages in JMS

See

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/concepts/xms_cconn_stastop.html

Answer (score 0):

@macpak: Are you sure you are connecting to right queue and/or u r connecting to correct queue manager? Are you sure that queue has some messages? IF you are using websphere MQ, using MQ explorer, you can view number of messages as well as number of open sessions.